# RabbitMQ using PhpAmqpLib

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I want to ask about rabbitmq using PHP.

I have 1 file ex : sender.php that the flow is:

1. open connection amqp
2. create channel
3. publish message
4. close channel
5. close connection

I create 200 rows to hit the sender.php via cronjob at the same time for this file.

> Example : every 5 minutes run 200 times of sender.php

But when I see the total queue, sometime the queue exact 200, but sometimes < 200.

The max client connection in apache set to 1000.
i'm using videlalvaro phpamqplib.

What wrong with my queue? can someone give me advice?

Thanks

Comment: Hello linda, could you add the code of sender.php ? And provide some information about the platform where your executing it ? RabbitMQ version, PHP version, phpamqplib version, ...